# CounterClockWise Repl does not print result

Tags: eclipse, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, counterclockwise

I follow gruid install CounterClockwise in eclipse(Juno) and run the sample project, the Repl is up, but it's only show the command what I type, without result. For example, when i type (+ 2 3), just show ==> (+ 2 3). The result is also not printed in the consol view. I take hours on network but did not find out solution on this.

But when I run (javax.swing.JOptionPane/showMessageDialog nil "IT-Homer"), the correct window is shown. So I think clojure is run ok, but only the result is not show in the repl.

When the repl runs up, it show that clojure 1.6.0 is used.

Pls give help, thank you.